# how to put and get from Map<Person, Map<List<String>, Integer>> personCache in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary, hashmap

I need to set up a local groupCache and personCache.

They have already been defined by my predecessor as:

```
        private Map<List<String>, Integer> groupCache;
        private Map<Person, Map<List<String>, Integer>> personCache;
```

So after I declare them:

```
    Map<List<String>,Integer> groupCache = new HashMap<List<String>,Integer>();
         Map<List<String>, Map<List<String>,Integer> > personCache = new HashMap ....
```

I'm having trouble mapping the data into groupCache, let alone building the personCache

Note there are two "layers" of HashMap. In the outer layer, a Person is a Class.

So I have potentially a bundle of Person objects such as person1, person2, person3...(# of persons is NOT fixed). Each person is like a leader of having 5 groups with 0-? members in each one of these groups.

In the inner layer, initially I have Group as a class. There are five groups, say group1, group2...

For simplicity, instead of using Group as a class, I use a list of String instead. So List strList has "A", "B", "C", "D", "E". (the # of groups is fixed for now)

For instance, I've built:

```
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>(5);

    strList.add("A");
    strList.add("B");
    strList.add("C");
    strList.add("D");
    strList.add("E");
```

For each group, I need to show the size of the group as an int. Say group1 or "A" has 5 people in it, group2 has 3 folks...

I have an integer array setup to account for the # of members:

```
     int[] intArr = { 5, 3, 2, 4, 4};
```

But I have since converted it to a list called intList:

```
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < intArr.length; index++)
    {
        intList.add(intArr[index]);
    }
```

I've tried a few ways such as:

```
     for (Integer number : intList) 
        for (String str : strList)
                groupCache.put(str, intList);
```

but it doesn't work.

Can someone help clarify how to

(1). use groupCache.put(...) in my case to create groupCache and then perosnCache?

Note: the # of members gets changed all the time--add or subtract a new member to and from one of the group.

The other part of the project already has a mechanism to update their tables to keep track of the latest # of new member in a group.

So every time there is an update, the program fires an event. I receive the event with an Person object and unwrap the person to see which group(s) under him/her has an increase or decrease of membership.

So I need to have HashMap to keep track of these arrays of numbers locally and need to update my array list as frequency as I can.

(2). how do I use groupCache.get(...) to compare between the existing # of members and the new # of members do it?

(3). What's missing from using the above enhanced for loop?

Thx much!

[EDIT] argh! after some more digging, it looks like what I need is to change the initial set up to  Map> personCache

[EDIT 2]
how I realize I can define it this way instead:

```
 private List<Integer> groupCache;
 groupCache = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 


  private Map<Person, List<Integer>> personCache;
  personCache = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

Now I can set up group1 with 5 people this way if I have to do it manually:

```
        groupCache.set(0, 5);
        groupCache.set(0, 5);
```

And I'm hopping to set up all five groups for person1 this way and so on,

```
    personCache.put(person1, groupCache);
```

So I have no problem putting together a method addPerson() using the above set up.

Question: do I remove a person or a group from a person?

I've tried groupCache.clear() or .remove(...). but is unsure how to methodically remove all elements.

I'll need that to set up a removePerson() method.

see below:

```
  public void removePerson(Person oldPerson) {
    if (personCache == null) 
        personCache = new HashMap<Unit, List<Integer>>();

        if (personCache.containsKey(oldPerson)) {
        .....
               }
            groupCache.clear();
            groupCache.remove(oldPerson);

            }
```

Comment: You can't use `cropCache.put(str, intList)` because the key is defined as `List<String>` and you're using `String` as parameter. Probably you have to redefine your map to `Map<String, List<Integer>>`.

Comment: Using anything mutable as key in a HashMap is a terrible idea. Collections like `List` calculate their hash code dynamically based on the current content. You don't want to change the hash code of a key ever. Guava's [MultiMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) is a simpler to use Map<Key, List<Value>> implementation in case you don't want to implement that on your own.

Comment: okay. Map<String, List<Integer>> is the simplest definition to do the  job.

Comment: I'll look up Guava's MultiMap to see if it makes my job easier! Thx

Comment: I just edited it the 2nd time and add a question about removing a Person or elements from my HashMap. Can someone help? Thx much.